# Iterate through list and handle StopIteration in Python beautifully

Tags: python, list, iterator, stopiteration

I am trying to iterate through a list, and I need to perform specific operation when and only when the iteration reached the end of the list, see example below:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]

data_iter = data.__iter__()
try:
    while True:
        item = data_iter.next()
        try:
            do_stuff(item)
            break # we just need to do stuff with the first successful item
        except:
            handle_errors(item) # in case of no success, handle and skip to next item
except StopIteration:
    raise Exception("All items weren't successful")
```

I believe this code isn't too Pythonic, so I am looking for a better way. I think the ideal code should look like this hypothetical piece below:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]

for item in data:
    try:
        do_stuff(item)
        break # we just need to do stuff with the first successful item
    except:
        handle_errors(item) # in case of no success, handle and skip to next item
finally:
    raise Exception("All items weren't successful")
```

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: replace `finally` with `else`?

Comment: Why do you have `'All items weren't successful'` instead of `"All items weren't successful"`? That middle apostrophe will break your string/exception if it runs. Also, to WolframH's point, see the [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) - `else` instead of `finally` should work.

Comment: It's worth noting that `except:` is a terrible thing - if it's just for example, fine, but in any real example, please only catch a specific exception.

Comment: Yes... `except Exception` at a minimum.

Comment: @thegrinner fixed, it was just mistype in a quick-and-dirty code to demonstrate the problem

Comment: @Lattyware thanks, I never use such `except:` in real code, as I've said, this is just quick-and-dirty example

Comment: @FogleBird `except Exception:` is almost worse - people expect it to catch everything and it won't. Catching a specific exception is always what you want.

Comment: I think it's much better than a bare except. `except Exception:` catches everything that you'd normally want to catch. It *doesn't* catch things like `KeyboardInterrupt`... which is usually the desired behavior. But yes, specific exceptions are always best.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `else` after a for loop, and the code within that `else` is only executed if you did not `break` out of the for loop:

```
data = [1, 2, 3]

for item in data:
    try:
        do_stuff(item)
        break # we just need to do stuff with the first successful item
    except Exception:
        handle_errors(item) # in case of no success, handle and skip to next item
else:
    raise Exception("All items weren't successful")
```

You can find this in the [documentation for the `for` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), relevant pieces shown below:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else`clause’s suite.

Comment: As I was typing it up. +1 - this is the best way of doing it.